# How to find all keyboard shortcuts to a process/program in Linux?

Tags: linux, suse

Is there a way to find all keyboard shortcuts for a given process/program in Linux(SuSe)? I have googled tons of stuff,but don't get anything useful. Could someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not documented, and not apparent from menu highlighting/markup, the only way to do this is by systematic experimentation.  Start by assuming that the shortcuts use one or more of the conventional key-modifiers (e.g., alt, control, shift).